# Ksql Only produce an event if there isn't the same event in the stream already

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Let's assume i have an event with the Key A and Attributes B,C and D. in my incoming stream the event looks like this:
A:{B="BVal", C="CVal", D="DVal"}
Now i just need the Information of A, B and C, thats why i am selecting B and C using ksql. Now my stream looks like this:
A:{B="BVal", C="CVal"}
Now the following event is produced to the incoming stream:
1:{B="Cat", C="Dog", D="Fish"}
As i am just selecting B and C, my event should looks like this:
1:{B="Cat", C="Dog"}
The problem i have is, that if i got an event looking like this:
1:{B="Cat", C="Dog", D="Rabbit"} creates the follwing event:
1:{B="Cat", C="Dog"}
Its the exact same event. Accordingly my question: How can i assure that i dont produce the exact same event twice? (just because its not necessary and i dont want my stream consuming application to reconsume the exact same event)

I can imagine some kind of comparision- maybe with a hash per key.
Maybe there are other best practices

Answer (score 0):

Kafka / KsqlDB do not pre-examine record content. Kafka accepts serialized bytes, then you're selecting them, which deserializes and presents a human readable output... That being said, a producer has no possibility of knowing what previous content "matches"; it simply appends bytes to a log. You'd need to externally store what's already been sent within your producer application to prevent duplicates within the topic itself. Or, from a consumer side, you can query the same store to prevent processing duplicates, but that's not possible in ksql.

Now, if you had a TABLE in ksql, it would dedupe based on the key, but seeing as you're replacing A by 1, that wouldn't do any good, and certainly wouldn't help values of B, C unless you scanned the entire table and compared every value object (again, not possible directly in ksql).

Or, you can try grouping / selecting distinct values, but depending on the query, it may still `EMIT` a record for each duplicate event until you restart the query